# How to Send Auto mail with out using SMTP because of blocked by network company

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

Please help me.
My problem is SMTP blocked by network company.
I'm using System.Net.Mail to send auto mail with smtp. gmail.com my app run very well when i connect network at home, but when i run app in company through company network, it's blocked. i try using port 587, 465, 25 but all blocked.
Please help me fix my issue, is there anyway to send auto mail in c# ?
Sorry for my English

Comment: Your company probably has a good reason to prevent normal employees from sending emails to external SMTP servers. It's a great way for a rogue employee to leak company information. TALK with your IT department rather than trying to subvert them.

Comment: you can use gmail API to send mails via https: https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages/send